# Unable to access a Drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, raid

I am new to this platform so I don't Know much about Ubuntu, Now I have installed the latest Ubuntu version that is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (64 bit), I already have windows 8 installed in my PC and I have unchecked the fast Startup option in but still I'm getting the following error....can anyone help me out...? 
Thanks in advance

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/mr-x/Movies n Songs: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/mr-x/Movies n Songs"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (669564927): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```